# Firebase pass token into parameter in angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I want to pass token into a variable so I can use it to call api from Backend. I have figured about

```
requestToken.subcribe((token) => {console.log(token);});
```

but it will only return to console screen.

Comment: Why don't you connect firebase from backend only

Comment: Because I'm building an web app where user can freely set up notifcation with schedule. I think it will be more efficiency if they can managed it from both side with button, input and such rather than asking Dev to set up schedule notify when they need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simple.
Store the token in a variable

```
export class AppComponent {
  token;
constructor() {}
```

and than use it

```
requestToken.subcribe((data) => {
      console.log(token);
      this.token = data;
    });
```

and `this.token` can be used anywhere inside the class

Comment: It's not working. The token value stay inside the method request token and that's it. When I try using it in other method, it return to null.

Comment: Nevermind. The amount of time for the browser to generate token is too slow, much slower than the speed the browser can generate other function so I got return null at the start alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
[...]

requestToken.subcribe((token) => {
   this.angukarFireAuth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(token);
   console.log(token);
});
```

To generate a custom token, you can use the Firebase Admin SDK.

Let suppose you are using NodeJs in backend then admin Node.js SDK offers a createCustomToken(uid, customClaims) method to do so. You can then send the generated token to the client to signInWithCustomToken. Learn more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens